# CSS: How to create <li> Pseudo Element in <ul> Level 1, but not in <ul> Level 2?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists, pseudo-element

**Challenge:**

- A pseudo element called `li:last-child:after` should get created for main navigation `ul.level_1`
- The pseudo element should NOT get created for subnavigation `ul.level_2`

---

**Coding:**

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px; height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

/*Creating the pseudo element */
li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

/*Creating the desired actions for main navigation li childs 1 to 5*/
li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(100px);}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(200px);}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(300px);}
li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
li:nth-child(5):hover:last-child:after { transform: translatex(500px);}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul class="level_1">
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 2</a></li>
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 3</a></li>
      <li class="submenu sibling">
         <ul class="level_2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Issue:** As you can see, currently there are two red squares moving around. Instead, only one square for `ul.level_1` should be existent. How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select only those li elements which are the direct children of the level_1 ul. At the moment you are selecting any li, at any level below the ul.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px; height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

/*Creating the pseudo element */
ul.level_1 > li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

/*Creating the desired actions for main navigation li childs 1 to 5*/
li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(100px);}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(200px);}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(300px);}
li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
li:nth-child(5):hover:last-child:after { transform: translatex(500px);}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul class="level_1">
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 2</a></li>
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 3</a></li>
      <li class="submenu sibling">
         <ul class="level_2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="sibling"><a href="#">Parent 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Happy coding.

```
ul.level_1 > li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```